'I anticipate in the prospect of 10 years (=within 10 years from now) the emergence of revanche-driven politicians.'
Is it correct and idiomatic usage to say,

I anticipate in the prospect of 10 years the emergence of revanche-driven politicians...

https://youtu.be/gCeCnbnIYI0?t=1964
to mean

Within 10 years from now (In the 10-years perspective) I envisage the emergence of revanche politics...

?

When speaking extemporaneously in an interview setting, even well-educated speakers often use poor grammar, because they change directions in the middle of a sentence.

That sentence is not in the transcript and anyway, they are non-native speakers.

@Lambie It maybe just a slip of tongue as Barmar pointed out. But what do you mean by  "That sentence is  not in the transcript and anyway, they are non-native speakers.." The speaker is Ukraine's ex-Foreign Minister and not someone you meet randomly on the streets.I appreciate the term "well-educated" in Barmar's comment

@JamesMathai What do you not understand about "that sentence is not in the transcript? Or they are non-native speakers?" A Ukrainian minister is not someone who one would expect to have correct English.

@Lambie I found that sentence in the transcript. I don't understand why the discussion on the use of r"evanche",  "revanchist" when OP's post doesn't ask for it.

OP has asked whether the phrase (in bold) is correct and idiomatic:

"I anticipate in the prospect of 10 years (=within 10 years from now) the emergence of revanche-driven politicians."

The sentence is not idiomatic.
To correct it, the phrase  "the prospect of 10 years" should be modified. The revised sentence would be:

"I anticipate the emergence of revanche-driven politicians within the next ten years."

The term "revanche" originates from French, meaning "revenge," and is indeed uncommon in English.
However, it was used aptly by Ukraine's ex-Foreign Minister to describe political ideologies focused on regaining lost territory or status, particularly in the context of nationalism or historical grievances.
Examples of "revanchist movements" can be found throughout history and across the globe.
For instance, French revanchism emerged after the Franco-Prussian War, driven by a desire to reclaim lost territories.
Similarly, German revanchism developed in response to territorial losses after World War I, with some seeking to recover areas ceded during the war.
revanche.
noun.
a policy or movement aimed at achieving the return of a nation's lost territory
revanchist.
noun.
: one who advocates or fights for the recovery of lost territory or status : one who advocates a policy of revanche

No.  "Anticipate" and "prospect" are redundant.  And "prospect" is misused in the example sentence.  "I anticipate in the next 10 years" is an idiomatic replacement for "I anticipate in the prospect of 10 years".
"Revanche" is not idiomatic.  It has a clear meaning that is appropriate in the sentence, but only some educated readers will know that meaning.

The original sentence was said by a minister of Foreign Affairs at a TV interview.

@Wittyhaire It's a fancy word that a minister might use to show off their education. Or you could have misheard "revenge".

Is the interview online so you could add a link to it in the question? @Wittyhaire

@Barmar  https://youtu.be/gCeCnbnIYI0?t=1964

Due to his Ukrainian accent, it's really hard to tell whether he's saying "revanche" or "revenge". Since he's not a native English speaker, I think "revenge" is much more likely. @Wittyhaire
